# input type="image" (submit button) for mobile

Tags: html, mobile-website

I am not an expert of mobile web design, and I tried to look on internet about it.
The only things that I found out that if I use an image button not always would be visualised on mobiles. I do not have mobiles where I can make direct tests to verify the real situation.

I wanted to know what are the cases and situation when an input type="image" button it is not visualised.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done limited mobile application development, but in the past I had trouble with image buttons on BlackBerry devices.  You can download various emulators to test your application with and view it as it would be viewed on the device.  This was very helpful for me.

[BlackBerry Emulators](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/resources/simulators.jsp)

There is an android emulator as part of the android sdk which can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html).

There is an iphone emulator as part of its sdk as well, but it will cost you some money to register.  That can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/develop.html).

Answer (score 2):

`input type="image"` is safe to use on mobile devices.

I've used it on several mobile website and haven't seen any major problems. Some handsets might change the presentation of the button (Nokia S60 browser will add a gray background that's larger than the image if I remember correctly).

[image: Example: Nokia S60 browser]

Comment: can you add a screenshot as example of this effect? Naturally if you have any :)

Comment: @Littlemad See my updated answer, sorry I can't remember the handset model

Comment: thx very much. It is still usable, not beautiful, but it is good that is usable.

Answer (score 0):

You can bet that on any Blackberry prior to 6.0 won't display type="image" or will give you unexpected results.  BB 6.0 uses webkit as it's browser engine so it's able to keep up with Android and iPhone.

Comment: How old are the Blackberry 6.0? and what is the latest version? I have no idea about blackberry. thx!